# Collision detection in tile-base game only applies to the file tile in the array

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

I've written a prototype in java that employs a movable character and tile-based graphics and game logic. The layout of each level is stored in a 10x10 2D array. When I use the following code to detect whether or not the player is colliding with a '1' (empty) tile, it only returns positive when the player is colliding with the final '1' tile in the array, why is this? I understand this method is incredibly inefficient.

```
for(int r = 0; r < levArray.length; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < levArray[0].length; c++) {
            if(levArray[r][c] == 1) {
                if(px >= r*64-9 && px <= (r+1)*64+11 && py >= c*64-30 && py <= (c+1)*64+30) {
                    isColliding = true;
                } else {
                    isColliding = false;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking every element of the level against the player position `(px,py)`. Since the only control in these loops is the iteration itself, the last comparison that happens is at the last cell. Any result from previous calculations will be overwritten by this last calculation.

As Kayaman says, you can break or return to exit the loop; better would be to check the player position against the level, instead of checking the level against the player. You know where the player is, if you convert that `px,py` coordinate into `r,c` coordinates you only have to look at one element in the level array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop looping (for example with break) when you find a collision. Now you loop all the way through and the isColliding variable will be set to whatever the last item in the array is.